# Walking Dead: what was the reason for massive initial death toll?

Tags: the-walking-dead

Assuming that everyone was already infected anyway, and the virus doesn't do anything until the host dies, what helped to kickstart the zombie apocalypse? Imo a society under martial law would've been able to handle zombies with a regular death rate, apparently too many people died too fast which overwhelmed the civilization.

Answer (score 3):

One clue can be found in the "Fear the Walking dead" spin-off.  A man sees his newly deceased wife, has no idea (and why should he) that the dearly departed have become ambulatory.  He walks up to her, thinking maybe she's having a seizure or something, and the next thing he knows, chomp, chomp.

Since the guy in CDC basically confirmed that everybody has the virus that scenario alone could have cause the creation of tens of thousands of Walkers.

Comment: Another clue from FTWD, as they gathered up the *biters* -- not willing to kill them, yet -- they accidentally created **herds** that were too numerous to safely deal with.

Comment: Also since 151,600 people dies on average per day that could easily escalate. (thats presuming the death rate in twd is the same as ours)

Comment: I've taken this into consideration. Let's say in the US ~7'000 people die every day, even if every zombie attacks ten people it's 70'000 by the end of first cycle and 700'000 by the end of the third. Police(who aren't shy about shooting people in the head), quarantine procedures, martial law and national guard should be able to handle the situation. Surely it's the end of the world as we know it, but I'd expect more of a Last of Us situation, rather than complete apocalypse. Something must've made initial toll way to high to handle and cripple military at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You've kind of answered your own question there. Since everyone was infected every normal death added to the undead and those undead began killing other still living people, thereby creating exponentially larger amounts of undead. However, as the proportion of undead to living increases civilisation starts to collapse very rapidly as the food supply lines collapse, medicines run out and power, water, waste disposal etc. break down. This kills many people from hunger, accidents or disease and they also become undead, adding to the exponential increase. By the time the enormity of the problem is realised, it's too late to contain it.

This explains how so many people were dead and the world was in such a mess by the time Rick came out of his coma [four or five weeks](https://www.businessinsider.com.au/when-does-fear-the-walking-dead-start-2015-8?r=US&IR=T) after going into hospital.

Comment: Wouldn't military survive in such condition? They are all physically fit to endure stress and rigors, internally equiped with both supplies and weapons, and more importantly they are rigid enough to act as a single entity and have chains of command and communication to quickly gather the required knowledge(shoot in the head, any dead person reanimates), transfer it to higher ups, educate the troops. From then a combination of quarantine and extermination with civilian evacuation to preastablished zones of strict control is a natural thing. For it not to work military itself must be crippled.

Comment: Later seasons show that some military units and bases have survived long after the initial collapse of civilization (e.g. in season 3 when The Governor and his men encounter a unit of soldiers that have only recently fled a military base that had finally been overrun), but they are isolated and no longer part of a cohesive national military force. The logistics and supply chains required to support a modern military would be impossible in a world in which civilization had totally collapsed.

Comment: @Which brings me to the question: why the civilization collapsed if there were means to contain the zombie apocalypse?

Comment: Well the means existed, possibly, but the justification for civilizational collapse in the series is that the zombie infection spreads too rapidly for those means to be put to use in a meaningful way. Think about a major natural disaster like a hurricane or an earthquake and the resources and logistics involved in responding to that, but then imagine the disaster happening everywhere, all over the world, all at the same time. By the time the scale of the zombie outbreak is apparent there is no way to contain it because it's already spread around the globe.